# RabbitSubscribe consume one message at a time

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

I'm using the nestjs golevelup rabbitmq library and am wondering if it is possible to use RabbitSubscribe but only consume one message at a time? Currently it will receive multiple messages before the first is finished processing which is causing updating issues. I've tried it with and without queue options to specify a channel that has a prefetch count of 1.

```
  @RabbitSubscribe({
    exchange: 'test_exchange',
    routingKey: 'test_update',
    queue: 'test_update',
    queueOptions: {
      channel: 'channel-2',
    },
  })
  public async updateItem(msg) {
    await this.service.updateItem(msg);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag to indicate if a message is being processed or not. It's probably not very efficient, but it should work.

```
import { Nack, RabbitSubscribe } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq';

class SomeService {
  private isProcessing = false;

  @RabbitSubscribe({
    exchange: 'test_exchange',
    routingKey: 'test_update',
    queue: 'test_update',
  })
  public async handleMessage(msg) {
    if (this.isProcessing) {
      return new Noack(true);
    }

    this.isProcessing = true;
    await this.service.updateItem(msg);
    this.isProcessing = false;

    return;
  }
}
```

If `updateItem` will fail for some reason, the message will be processed again.